# finding selectors by specific css values with ack/grep regex

Tags: regex, grep, ack

I have the following two selectors in my css, laid out with this formatting:

```
// file1.css
#myId {
    margin-right:0;
    color:#f00;
}

// file2.css
#otherId { margin-right:0; color: #f00 }
```

My goal is to obtain the selector and the color value using a ack/grep search.

if I:

`ack-grep '(^.*color:\s+\d+)'`

I'll get:

```
file1.css
color:#f00;

file2.css
#otherId { margin-right:0; color: #f00 }
```

This search worked fine for `file2.css`, but not so well for `file1.css`, probably because I use `^` to match to the beginning of a line.. how would I consistently match back to the beginning of some css selector (starting with either an id or a class or tagname)?

to be more obvious, I want:

```
file1.css
#myId {margin-right:0; color:#f00;

file2.css
#otherId { margin-right:0; color: #f00 }
```

(and the selector doesn't necessarily have to be an ID.. should I match back to previous `}` or beginning of file?

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10891045/288906

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither grep nor ack supports multi-line regexes:

[ack FAQ](http://search.cpan.org/dist/ack/ack-base#Can_I_do_multi-line_regexes?)

There are other alternatives, like pcregrep. I would use some CSS parser though.