# Extract email address from view-source of website page

Tags: xpath, spreadsheet

Trying to extract email address from page source of https://www.dice.com/jobs/detail/Process-Engineer-Lead-Kforce-Inc.-San-Antonio-TX-78288/kforcecx/ITWQG1496436?icid=sr1-1p&q=Senior%20Process%20Engineer&l=78288

I have list of links in columnA
ColumnB =importxml(A1, "//a[@href]/text()[contains(.,'@')]")
It is only extracting newdicesupport@dice.com not KJOHNSON@KFORCE.COM or any personal emails from page source.

Can you point out to me where is the wrong step in the code I took?.

Answer (score 0):

That e-mail is inside a comment, so you need to access the comment ([Accessing Comments in XML using XPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784745/accessing-comments-in-xml-using-xpath)). Otherwise you can consider also 'input' nodes (that email is contained in the source, two times).